# Unable to boot Windows 10 after installing Ubuntu. Legacy boot

Tags: linux, ubuntu, windows, dual-boot

I installed Ubuntu along with Windows 10. I am able to boot Ubuntu after that, but unable to boot up Windows. 
I am new to Linux. When I reboot the laptop, the only picture I see is:

[image]

I performed a boot repair, but check box "Repair Windows boot files" is grayed out.

I tried to reinstall the GRUB by using this command:

```
grub-install /dev/sda
```

But got message showing:

```
Installing for i386-pc platform.
grub-install: error: cannot open directory ' /boot/grub/i386-pc':  no such file or directory
```

[image]

What are my options? I really need my Windows back. 
I have dell laptop and tried Windows recovery, by pushing F8 multiple times, but was not able to enter recovery menu. 
Please help...

Comment: Don't use boot repair, it makes sometimes things even worst. `sudo apt install boot-info-script cl-awk`  You need packagesource universe.  `sudo bootinfoscript` this command creates a file named RESULTS.txt in your current working directory. Post the file https://pastebin.ca/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem right now is that your Ubuntu is installed with BIOS support, and since Windows 8 uses EFI support you need to make both the same in order to use them in dual-boot

This is [Ubuntu's official documentation about UEFI](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI)

Basically what you need to do is:

- Enable "only-uefi" boot mode in your BIOS settings.
- Use a UEFI Ubuntu Image in your liveUSB
- Perform a normal installation as the guide shows
- See if the other OS are listed when installin grub.

Answer (score 0):

try looking up your motherboards name and finding which key is used to enter its BIOS when it starts up. (most likely f2, although i cant say because i dont know the motherboard model just the brand) turn your pc all the way off, turn it back on, when the dell logo appears try tapping f2 repeatedly. Once you get into your bios, navigate to the boot order and change windows to be higher than ubuntu.